# How to use UDF in where clause in Scala Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I'm trying to check if 2 Double columns are equal in a Dataframe to a certain degree of precision, so 49.999999 should equal 50. Is it possible to create a UDF and use it in a where clause? I am using Spark 2.0 in Scala.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `udf` but there is no need for that:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val precision: Double = ???

df.where(abs($"col1" - $"col2") < precision)
```

`udf` call would work the same way, but be less efficient

```
df.where(yourUdf($"col1", $"col2"))
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming ctx is SQL context

```
ctx.udf.register("areEqual", (x: Double, y: Double, precision : Double) => abs(x-y)< prescision
```

and then

```
df.where(areEqual($"col1",$"col2",precision))
```